# Algolia autocomplete modify query before POST

Tags: algolia

My problem is that I have a reserve character in my query string that I need to remove before posting data to Algolia's autocomplete widget.  The character that I need to remove from my search is a dash ("-").  Basically, when ever the user types in the dash I want to replace it with a space (" ") on the backend post to Algolia for processing.

Is that possible?

Comment: Algolia considers all dashes as spaces for its relevance matching by default. So "foo-bar" will be equivalent to "foo bar". Do you see any different results between the two?

Comment: You're correct.  I refactored some of my indices and things are working well.